# How $xN · yN = yN · xN$ is equivalent, to $xN · yN · (xN )^{−1} · (yN )^{−1} = N$.

Tags: group-theory

How $xN · yN =
yN · xN$ is   equivalent, to
$xN · yN · (xN )^{−1} · (yN )^{−1} = N$.

Where N is normal subgroup.

**$EDIT: 1$**

$x \in G $, $y \in G$ and $xN$ is coset.

Comment: This is no different to proving that, for any $x,y$ in a group $G$, $xy=yx$ is equivalent to $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1$, as the equivalence is true for the cosets if and only if it is true in the quotient group (since $N$ is normal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If $(xN)(yN)=(yN)(xN)$ then $(xN)(yN)=(Ny)(Nx)$ and so $(xN)(yN)(x^{-1}N)(y^{-1}N)=N$ and then $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}N=N$ or $[x,y]\in N$ and vice versa. Since $N$ is a normal subgroup so for all $g\in G$, $gN=Ng$.

Comment: How $yN$ is equal to $Ny$ ?? for this condition we should have given $y \in N$

Comment: @TLE: $N$ is normal in G so for $y\in G$, $yNy^{-1}=N$. This means that $yN=Ny$.

Comment: Well done, once again, dear friend! ${{+^+}^+}^+$

Comment: @amWhy: You made for my sky many stars here. Thanks :-0

Answer (score 4):

Well since $N$ is normal, you are dealing with the elements of the group $G/N$. So, multiplying both sides of $xN · yN · (xN )^{−1} · (yN )^{−1} = N $ on the right with first $yN$ and then $xN$ yields

$$
xN\cdot yN=N\cdot yN\cdot xN
$$
Since $N$ is the identity of that group, the right hand side is just $yN\cdot xN$

The converse follows by just reversing the steps.